# Data not populating in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here is my schema

```
var employee =  
    {
        empCode : { type : String  ,  unique: true ,  required : true },
        firstName : { type : String  , required : true },
        lastName : { type : String },
        email :  { type : String  },
        DOJ :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
        DOB :{ type : Date  },
        phoneNo : { type : String },
        authentication : 
            {
                username : { type : String },
                password : { type : String }
            },
        dsg : 
            [{
                designationID: [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'designation'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }             
            }],
        grd : 
            {
                grade : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'grade'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        dpt :
            {
                departmentID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId ,ref:'department'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        manager : 
            {
                managerID : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'employee'},
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        rol :
            {   
                roleID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'role'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },

        status : {type:Boolean}
    }
```

and i wannt to populate like this

```
empController.prototype.list=function(callback){
    objMdlEmp.find()
    .populate('designationID')
    .populate('grade')
    .exec(function(err, records){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);return;
            callback(false , config.msg.SOMTHING_WRONG);
            return;
        }else {
            callback(true , records);   
        }
    })
};
```

but another document data is not showing, 
when i put like this my schema then only its showing , but i need to add effFrom and effTo data also

`dsg : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'designation'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant populate embedded fields in mongoose, but you can use some workarounds

1) Keep your related data in another field like so

```
var employee = {
    grd: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'grade'},
    grdData: {
        grade: [],
        effFrom: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        effTo: {type: Date}
    }
};
```

2) Use plugins like [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate)

```
objMdlEmp.find().deepPopulate('grd.grade').exec(function (err, records) { ... });
```